# Callback inside renderToolbar in Onsen UI + React app doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, onsen-ui, onsen-ui2

I'm trying to use Onsen UI + React for an application that needs to have a splitter and navigation. The Page object uses the function *renderToolbar* in which the buttons with the method are defined to open the Splitter.

This doesn't when I click on button from toolbar, but works when click on button from page. Why?

Here is full code:

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {
    Toolbar, Page, Button, ToolbarButton, Icon, Input,
    Splitter, SplitterSide, SplitterContent
} from 'react-onsenui';

import SecondPage from './SecondPage'

export default class MainPage extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            isOpen: false
        };

        this.show = this.show.bind(this);
    }

    /**
     * Show side menu
     */
    show() {
        this.setState({
            isOpen: true
        });
    }

    /**
     * Hide side menu
     */
    hide() {
        this.setState({
            isOpen: false
        });
    }

    /**
     * Push page to navigation stack
     */
    pushPage() {
        this.props.navigator.pushPage({component: SecondPage});
    }

    /**
     * Render top toolbar (action bar)
     */
    renderToolbar() {
        return (
            <Toolbar>
                <div className="right">
                    <ToolbarButton onClick={this.show}><Icon icon='menu'/></ToolbarButton>  <--- DON'T WORK!
                </div>
            </Toolbar>
        );
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Splitter>
                <SplitterSide
                    side='left'
                    collapse={true}
                    isOpen={this.state.isOpen}
                    onClose={this.hide.bind(this)}
                    isSwipeable={true}>
                    <Page>
                        <div>Menu content</div>
                    </Page>
                </SplitterSide>
                <SplitterContent>
                    <Page renderToolbar={this.renderToolbar}>
                        <div>Main content</div>
                        <Button onClick={this.show}>Open</Button>  <--- WORK!
                    </Page>
                </SplitterContent>
            </Splitter>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After many variants, I realized that the function renderToolbar also need have binding, so finally code:

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {
    Toolbar, Page, Button, ToolbarButton, Icon, Input,
    Splitter, SplitterSide, SplitterContent
} from 'react-onsenui';

import SecondPage from './SecondPage'

export default class MainPage extends React.Component {

    // const rightDirect = "right";
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            isOpen: false
        };

        this.hide = this.hide.bind(this);
        this.show = this.show.bind(this);
        this.renderToolbar = this.renderToolbar.bind(this);
    }

    /**
     * Show side menu
     */
    show() {
        this.setState({
            isOpen: true
        });
    }

    /**
     * Hide side menu
     */
    hide() {
        this.setState({
            isOpen: false
        });
    }

    /**
     * Push page to navigation stack
     */
    pushPage() {
        this.props.navigator.pushPage({component: SecondPage});
    }

    /**
     *
     */
    renderToolbar() {
        console.log('Render TB', this);
        return (
            <Toolbar>
                <div className="right">                        
                    <ToolbarButton onClick={this.show}><Icon icon='menu'/></ToolbarButton>
                </div>
            </Toolbar>
        );
    }

    /**
     *
     * @returns {XML}
     */
    render() {
        return (
            <Splitter>
                <SplitterSide
                    side='left'
                    collapse={true}
                    isOpen={this.state.isOpen}
                    onClose={this.hide}
                    isSwipeable={true}>
                    <Page>
                        <div>Menu content</div>
                    </Page>
                </SplitterSide>
                <SplitterContent>
                    <Page renderToolbar={this.renderToolbar}>
                        <div>Main content</div>
                    </Page>
                </SplitterContent>
            </Splitter>
        );
    }
}
```